# Duplicate alerts across multiple enviornments

Tags: prometheus

I have 5 different data centers, all requiring the same alerting. I need a new alert to be triggerd each time a data center exceeds the threshold.

Do I have to duplicte every alert 5 times to be able to get independent alerts from each data center?

If I create one alert for all data centers and multiple data centers trigger the alert, only one alert will be sent out.

Comment: Prometheus creates an alert for every set of labels which caused the firing of the alert. Most likely your alertmanager groups them for you. If this is the case look into `group by` [configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route) of alertmanager.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Does this work for sum queries? For example, if I wanted to trigger an alert if the sum of a number of metrics is not equal to 1 in each DC?

Comment: For `sum` - no. For `sum by (label1,label2)` - yes. You always can go to Graph page of your prometheus instance, paste expr of your rule, and see what is returned. If it returns multiple time series your rule can create multiple alerts. Alternatively, you could try modify question and add current rule, we will look into it.

Comment: No, thats fine! sum by was all I needed! still getting used to what expressions I can use! thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to duplicate every alert 5 times.

Your alerting rules can use metrics of different instances, cluster (or whatever), as long as they have the same name.

Simplest example of this:

```yaml
 # Alert for any instance that is unreachable.
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} is down."
```

This alerting rule checks if metric `up` returns 0 for any set of labels. If so, alert with the same set of labels as your metric (and a couple additional) is created.

If metric `up` returns 0 for multiple sets of metrics - alert will be created with every of this sets.

As you could see example alert rule includes summary and description. They are generated depending on labels `instance` and `job` of your initial metric.

More specific for your case could be something like:

```yaml
  - alert: MemOveruse
    expr: sum (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) by (instance) * 100 < 25
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} uses more than 75% of memory"
      desciption: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} has less than {{ $value }}% memory free."
```

Rule will be calculated for every instance, and for every satisfying instance alert will be fired.

You can check your rules (retrospectively) by pasting your expr at Graph page of own Prometheus. When you see parts of graphics yo alert would have been fired (or became pending, depending on presence of `for` clause in alert rule)

Demo example of applied rules can be seen at [prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/rules)

More on configuration of [alerting](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) and [recording](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) rules read in official documentation.